# Generate combinations for representing a number

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Question:

> Given infinite number of quarters (25 cents), dimes (10 cents), nickels (5 cents), and pennies (1 cents), calculate the number of ways of representing n cents.

My answer:

```
public static int generateComb(int n){
    if(n < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    int ways = generateComb(n-25) + generateComb(n-10) + generateComb(n-5) + generateComb(n-1);
    return ways;
}
```

Please tell me if my implementation is correct or not.

Comment: Your algorithm is more of permutation where (1, 5) is different from (5, 1).

Comment: can you guys suggest a method..?

Answer (score 2):

One fix would be to insure that no recursive call ever uses a coin larger than the last one used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys..I was able to get it:

```
public static int generateComb(int n, int denom){

    int next_denom = 0;
    switch(denom){
        case 25:
            next_denom = 10;
            break;
        case 10:
            next_denom = 5;
            break;
        case 5:
            next_denom = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 1;
    }

    int ways = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i*denom <= n ; i++){
        ways+= generateComb(n-i*denom, next_denom);
    }
    return ways;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as your solution but slightly shorter and supports arbitrary denominations.

```
private static int generateComb(int amount, Collection<Integer> denominations) {
  if (amount == 0) return 1;
  if (denominations.isEmpty()) return 0;

  List<Integer> denominationsList = new ArrayList<Integer>(denominations);
  Collections.sort(denominationsList, Collections.reverseOrder());

  int currentDenomination = denominationsList.remove(0);
  int ways = 0;
  for (int total = 0; total <= amount; total += currentDenomination) {
    ways += generateComb(amount - total, denominationsList);
  }

  return ways;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution -

```
int[] arr = {5, 3 , 1};
int sum = 10;
countNway(arr, sum, 0);

public int countNway(int[] arr, int sum, int start){

    if(start>arr.length){
        return 0;
    }
    if(sum==0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(sum<0){
        return 0;
    }
    int result =0;
    for(int i= start;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<=(sum/arr[i]); j++){
            result += countNway(arr, sum -arr[i]*j, i+1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```